# Is it easy to prove that $\sum_n |X(\mathbb{F}_{q^n})| t^n$ is rational?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, zeta-functions

**Background:** Let $X$ be an algebraic variety over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$. One  of the successes of Etale cohomology - previously achieved by Dwork-  was proving the rationality of the Zeta function of X, defined as 
$$Z(X,t)=\textrm{exp}\left(\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{|X(\mathbb{F}_{q^n})|t^n}{n}\right).$$

As a corollary, we get the rationality of $tZ'(X,t)/Z(X,t)$, which is the sum

$P(X,t)=\sum_n |X(\mathbb{F}_{q^n})| t^n.$

**Question:** Is there an elementary way to see that $P(x,t)$ is a rational function? Note that this is strictly weaker than asking whether $Z(X,t)$ is a rational function.

Comment: Actually $Z'(X,t)/Z(X,t)$ is not $P(X,t)$ but $P(X,t)/t$.

Comment: For curves, the rationality of the zeta function follows easily from the expression of the zeta function in terms of divisors and Riemann-Roch. But I don't see how to get the rationality of $P$ directly for curves.

Answer (score 11):

Not an answer to the question: in a 1976 Transactions of the AMS paper, Catarina Kiefe shows that the logarithmic derivative of zeta is rational for sets *definable* over finite fields (it is NOT necessarily true that zeta itself is, as she points out in the paper). So, the good news is that the rationality of $Z^\prime/Z$ is strictly weaker than rationality of $Z,$ the bad news is that she uses Dwork's result (and a bunch of model theory, though the paper is quite short). The fact that she makes no reference to a direct proof of such a result for varieties may be a sign that none was known at the time.

Comment: That's awesome! Thinking about it now, it sound similar to what Terry Tao does in his paper on polynomial expalnders:http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.2894.